# Transforming into list-comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, primes

I'm given a number (n), as well as an array of possible divisors for that number. I'm supposed to return a list of all the possible prime numbers of range (n) in reverse order, and it has to be written in one line via list-comprehension.

I've written something with one line that gets the output necessary, but I can't figure out how to write it as a list-comprehension.

The divisor:

```
DOUBLE = 2
    divisors = [i for i in range(DOUBLE, math.ceil(n/DOUBLE))]
    non_primes = []
    for item in divisors:
        for item2 in divisors:
            non_primes += [item*item2]
```

This is the code I have:

```
return list(set(range(2, n)) - set(non_primes))[::-1]
```

This is the docstring included with the question:

```
    """
    Given a number and an array of possible divisors,
    return a list of all the primes in the same range in
    reverse order.
    Use list comprehension in a single line.
    :param n: a non-negative integer
    :returns: a list of prime numbers
    :Example:
    >>> primes(10)
    [7, 5, 3, 2]
    """
```

Comment: Have you tried [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

Comment: Do you want the divisor search or the return written as a list comprehension?

Comment: What is the variable `DOUBLE` for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension that iterates an integer from `n` to `2` in reverse order, and retain only those that are either one of the given divisors themselves, or cannot be divided by any of the divisors:

```
[i for i in range(n, 1, -1) if i in divisors or all(i % d for d in divisors)]
```

Comment: sneaky usage of modulo and Truthyness of != 0 - me likes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
import math
n = 100
DOUBLE = 2
divisors = [i for i in range(DOUBLE, math.ceil(n/DOUBLE))]

#Get primes
print(list(set(range(2, n)) - set([ item*item2 for item in divisors for item2 in divisors]))[::-1])
#[97, 89, 83, 79, 73, 71, 67, 61, 59, 53, 47, 43, 41, 37, 31, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2]
```

The for loop

```
for item in divisors:
        for item2 in divisors:
            non_primes += [item*item2]
```

is converted to

```
[ item*item2 for item in divisors for item2 in divisors]
```

Also as suggested in the comment, you can simplify the double for loop by using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as below.

```
import math
import itertools
n = 100
DOUBLE = 2
divisors = [i for i in range(DOUBLE, math.ceil(n/DOUBLE))]

#Find all combinations of divisors
prod = itertools.product(divisors, repeat=2)

#Run through all combinations to get non primes
non_primes = [t[0]*t[1] for t in prod]

#Get primes
print([item for item in list(range(2, n)) if item not in non_primes][::-1])
```

Instead of doing set difference, you can also do

```
import math
import itertools
n = 100
DOUBLE = 2
divisors = [i for i in range(DOUBLE, math.ceil(n/DOUBLE))]

#Find all combinations of divisors
prod = itertools.product(divisors, repeat=2)

#Run through all combinations to get non primes
non_primes = [t[0]*t[1] for t in prod]

#Get primes
print([item for item in list(range(2, n)) if item not in non_primes][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

My sugesstion would be to really incorprate it as a one-liner.

**Code**

```
def getReversedPrimes(n):
    return sorted(set(range(2, n)) - set([k*l for k in range(2, int(n/2)) for l in range(2, int(n/2))]), reverse=True)


print(getReversedPrimes(10))
print(getReversedPrimes(100))
```

**Output**

```
[7, 5, 3, 2]
[97, 89, 83, 79, 73, 71, 67, 61, 59, 53, 47, 43, 41, 37, 31, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2]
```

**Explanation**

1. The non-primes do not need to be built from list comprehension. `range` returns a generator object that can be used for iteration righ away.
2. List comprehensions can be chained or "nested", too, like normal loops.
3. The built-in function `sorted` with the argument flag `reversed` ensures that the ouput is in reversed order. A `set` is not necessarily sorted.

---

By the way, nice art to use substraction on sets to take away elements from the first set.